assert no calls to function
In a Kotlin project we have a DateTimeProvider class which basically provides methods to get now:Instant and today:LocalDate. We introduced this class earlier to easier mock time in time based tests.
I would like to enforce the usage of this provider by verifying that no class (except DateTimeProvider) makes calls to LocalDate.now() or Instant.now().
I found Konsist to be promising in that regard but could not come up with a way to do it. Do you have any ideas?

Asking ChatGPT proves to be a valid way to get ideas:
class EnforceDateTimeProviderUsageTest : FunSpec({

val scope = Konsist
    .scopeFromProduction()
    .files
    .filter { it.name != "DateTimeProvider" }

  listOf(
    "LocalDate.now()", 
    "LocalDateTime.now()", 
    "Instant.now()"
  ).forEach { forbiddenCall ->
      scope.filter { it.text.contains(forbiddenCall) }.shouldBeEmpty()
  } 
})


The ArchUnit-based solution as a JUnit test would be:
@com.tngtech.archunit.junit.ArchTest
var `DateTimeProvider is used to get current instant or date` =
    com.tngtech.archunit.lang.syntax.ArchRuleDefinition
    .noClasses().that().doNotHaveFullyQualifiedName(DateTimeProvider::class.qualifiedName)
    .should().callMethod(LocalDate::class.java, "now")
    .orShould().callMethod(LocalDateTime::class.java, "now")
    .orShould().callMethod(Instant::class.java, "now")
    .because("DateTimeProvider should be used, as it makes it easier to mock time in time based tests")

